# Getting missing dependency error on installing erpnext on cpanel centos

Tags: python, cpanel, erpnext

I am trying to install `ERPnext` on my `cpanel`.

But I am getting `Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.15()(64bit)` this message from the script.

I have googled it but no helpful material was found .

As far as I knows from my research I have to install `mysql-devel` on my server but when I tryed to install it. I gets a message that it is already installed on the server.

Any idea how can I get it resolved or what should I do

Image of my terminal
[image: Screenshot of my terminal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error resolved by changing in `yum.config` file of `etc` directory.
We have to remove `mysql` from exclude-list.

Look for more info i the [Cpanel mysql python forum](https://forums.cpanel.net/f5/mysql-python-centos-release-5-8-a-272031.html).

Comment: By this the current error was resolved but I was stuck at mysql conflict error